# how to access tree elements in html using macro

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am a newbie in macro moreso using macro to access websites but I need a code to click a tree node. The HTML code is:

```
<html id="ext-gen3" class=" ext-strict x-viewport" decorator="blank">
    <head></head>
    <body id="ext-gen4" class="ext-gecko ext-gecko3 cwc-view x-border-layout-ct" onload="cwc.getFrameworkWindow()">
        <div id="cwc_header" class=" masthead x-border-panel" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1428px; height: 27px;"></div>
        <div id="cwcNavPanel" class=" x-panel cwc-navPanel x-border-panel" style="width: 220px; left: 0px; top: 56px;">
            <div id="ext-gen17" class="x-panel-bwrap">
                <div id="ext-gen18" class="x-panel-tbar x-panel-tbar-noheader" style="width: 220px;"></div>
                <div id="ext-gen19" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader" style="width: 218px; height: 490px;">
                    <div id="cwcAccordionNav" class=" x-panel x-panel-noborder" style="width: 218px;">
                        <div id="ext-gen44" class="x-panel-bwrap">
                            <div id="ext-gen45" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader x-panel-body-noborder" style="overflow: auto; width: 218px; height: 490px;">
                                <div id="ROOT/Favorites and Dashboards" class="x-panel x-panel-noborder x-tree x-panel-collapsed" style="width: auto;"></div>
                                <div id="ROOT/Change_/Fulfillment Tasks" class="x-panel x-panel-noborder x-tree x-panel-collapsed" style="width: auto;"></div>
                                <div id="ROOT/Change Management" class="x-panel x-panel-noborder x-tree" style="width: auto;">
                                    <div id="ext-gen84" class="x-panel-header x-panel-header-noborder x-unselectable x-accordion-hd" style="-moz-user-select: none; cursor: pointer;"></div>
                                    <div id="ext-gen85" class="x-panel-bwrap" style="display: block; visibility: visible; position: static; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: auto;">
                                        <div id="ext-gen86" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noborder" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
                                            <ul id="ext-gen87" class="x-tree-root-ct x-tree-arrows">
                                                <div class="x-tree-root-node">
                                                    <li class="x-tree-node"></li>
                                                    <li class="x-tree-node">
                                                        <div id="ROOT/Change Management/Open New Change" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on" ext:tree-node-id="ROOT/Change Management/Open New Change">
                                                            <span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span>
                                                            <img class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow" src="/SM/js/extjs/resources/images/default/s.gif" alt=""></img>
                                                            <img class="x-tree-node-icon cwc-tree-noIcon-node" unselectable="on" src="/SM/js/extjs/resources/images/default/s.gif" alt=""></img>
                                                            <a class="x-tree-node-anchor" tabindex="1" href="" hidefocus="on">
                                                                <span unselectable="on" qtip="Open New Change"></span>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="x-tree-node"></li>
                                                </div>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="ROOT/Configuration Management" class="x-panel x-panel-noborder x-tree x-panel-collapsed" style="width: auto;"></div>
                                <div id="ROOT/Fulfillment Request" class="x-panel x-panel-noborder x-tree x-panel-collapsed" style="width: auto;"></div>
                                <div id="ROOT/Incident Management" class="x-panel x-panel-noborder x-tree x-panel-collapsed" style="width: auto;"></div>
                                <div id="ROOT/Knowledge Management" class="x-panel x-panel-noborder x-tree x-panel-collapsed" style="width: auto;"></div>
                                <div id="ROOT/Problem Management" class="x-panel x-panel-noborder x-tree x-panel-collapsed" style="width: auto;"></div>
                                <div id="ROOT/Service Desk" class="x-panel x-panel-noborder x-tree x-panel-collapsed" style="width: auto;"></div>
                                <div id="ROOT/Service Level Management" class="x-panel x-panel-noborder x-tree x-panel-collapsed" style="width: auto;"></div>
                                <div id="defaultTreePanelID" class="x-panel x-panel-noborder x-tree" style="width: auto;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="cwcFavMgrPanel" class=" x-panel x-panel-noborder x-hide-display"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="cwcCenterPanel" class=" x-tab-panel cwc-centerPanel x-border-panel" style="left: 228px; top: 35px; width: 1200px;"></div>
        <!--

         Telephony Applet 

        -->
        <iframe id="ext-gen152" class="ext-shim" frameborder="0" src="/SM/js/extjs/resources/images/default/s.gif" style="display: none; visibility: visible; z-index: 20000; left: 118px; top: 202px; width: 108px; height: 35px;"></iframe>
        <div id="ext-gen153" class="x-shadow" style="z-index: 20001; left: 118px; top: 202px; width: 108px; height: 35px; display: none;"></div>
        <div id="ext-comp-808428" class="x-tip" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20002; visibility: hidden; width: 108px; left: 114px; top: 199px; display: none;"></div>
        <div id="cwcNavPanel-xsplit" class="x-layout-split x-layout-split-west x-splitbar-h" style="left: 220px; top: 56px; height: 520px;"></div>
        <div id="ext-gen50" class=" x-unselectable x-splitbar-proxy x-splitbar-proxy-h" style="-moz-user-select: none;"></div>
        <div id="ext-gen154" style="position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px; visibility:…; text-transform: none; letter-spacing: normal; width: auto;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

from the site, I want to click the one marked as "open new change". Below is the image of the site:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4YInJe_XRdfaERFOHl4Tnp5Zlk/edit?usp=sharing

From what i've read, this is what i need to do:

```
Sub TestLogin(user As String, pass As String)

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objCol As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "**************"

    WaitTilLoad IE

    IE.document.getElementByID("LoginUsername").Value = user
    IE.document.getElementByID("LoginPassword").Value = pass

    IE.document.getElementByID("loginBtn").Click

    WaitTilLoad IE
    WaitForSeconds 3

'THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE CODE. I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO ACCESS IT. BELOW IS NOT DOING ANYTHING
    IE.document.getElementByID("ROOT/Change Management/Open New Change").Click  

    WaitTilLoad IE
    WaitForSeconds 3

End Sub
```

I tried looking for answers in google but i dont know how to word my query or how to properly search to get more precise answers. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, anybody who can help at least point me in the right direction? Thanks.